# I need a screensaver that shows the desktop background only with a login prompt

Tags: windows, screensaver

Does anyone know of a Windows XP screensaver that will show a login prompt with the currently selected desktop background being visible behind the login prompt?   The screensavers for windows don't do this... they show a login prompt without a background.

Even better if it can display the "live desktop background".

Comment: Would that not be a security issue and defeat the reason for using screensavers in many cases? Interested to know more about why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you turn off the Welcome screen you get the same effect by logging out or locking the computer. One could write a short [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script:

`Run %windir%\system32\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation` (locks the workstation, like hitting Win+L),

I think, compile it, change the extension to .scr, and use that for a screensaver.

Comment: your right.  the answer was to go into the Control Panel and choose "Change the Way users login and logoff"  and then set it to "Do not use Login Screen".   That did it.  Thanks.